# Stopping rsync without leaving temporary files behind

Tags: rsync

When copying files from directory `A` to `B` with `rsync` using

```
$ rsync -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")  A/ B/
```

a file called `filename` in `A` will temporarily be called something on the form `.filename.9Tcfsa` in `B` while being transferred. That is, `rsync` adds some random characters to the name until the transfer is complete.

If I interrupt `rsync` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> while transferring `filename`, the temporary file `.filename.9Tcfsa` is left in `B`. Since my `rsync` command never removes any files from `B`, each interruption of `rsync` will leave another temporary file in `B`. This becomes annoying litter.

Is it possible to stop `rsync` and have it also removing the temporary file?

**UPDATE:**
Since other people seem not to experience the issue above, I am providing a script with output to demonstrate what I see on my machine.

Script `rsynctest.sh`:

```
#/!bin/bash
mkdir -p A
mkdir -p B
echo "Creating a 1 GB file in A..."
dd if=/dev/zero of=A/bigfile bs=1M count=1000 >& /dev/null
echo "Now press CTRL-C to interrupt rsync."
rsync -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")  A/ B/
```

Output when running the script twice:

```
$ ./rsynctest.sh 
Creating a 1 GB file in A...
Now press CTRL-C to interrupt rsync.
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.0]
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(521) [generator=3.1.0]
$ ./rsynctest.sh 
Creating a 1 GB file in A...
Now press CTRL-C to interrupt rsync.
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.0]
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(521) [generator=3.1.0]
$ ls -a B
.  ..  .bigfile.KvDV0T  .bigfile.MbalWJ
$
```

Notice that the last `ls` command reveals that `B` contains two temporary files.

Comment: I've never seen that behaviour, but if you can't find another way around it then you could use `-T` to specify a different directory in which to write the temp files (`/tmp` perhaps, if it's big enough).

Comment: I agree with @Flup - the default behaviour for rsync is to remove temporary files when it is interrupted.  Are you sure that's the exact command you're running, and are there any weird permissions issues in `B/` which might prevent deletions?

Comment: The behavior happens for sure. I can reconstruct it over and over. Have you tried it? My `rsync` version is  3.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. It happen even when `A` and `B` are local folders on the same drive in my own home directory.

Comment: I do agree, specifying a temporary directory is a solution I will resort to, but I would still like to know if `rsync` can clean up temporary files in a situation like above, i.e. can I stop `rsync` in a "clean way".

Comment: Can you just check with `alias | grep rsync` from whichever user is running the command?  The reason for asking these questions is that the default behaviour is supposed to be what you want, so if it's not doing that, something's broken and therefore there's no obvious solution.  There are no flags to make `rsync` behave how you want, because it's supposed to by default and the flags change it to how you don't want.

Comment: @EightBitTony - `alias | grep rsync` gives nothing. I have updated my question with a script and output.

Comment: @DustByte still no joy, tried two other machines (another Debian, and Ubuntu 15) and your script and can't force the behaviour you're seeing.  I don't have access to that specific version of `rsync` though. Any other software running which might be doing this?

Comment: It's a bug - fixed in 3.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: It's a bug in `rsync` 3.1.0.

This is a note from the [3.1.1. release notes](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/src/rsync-3.1.1-NEWS),

> Fixed a failure to remove the partial-transfer temp file when
>   interrupted (and rsync is not saving the partial files).

Upgrade your version of `rsync`.

**Previous stuff**

I've just tested this on my system.

```
tony@trinity:~$ uname -a
Linux trinity 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux
tony@trinity:~$ cat /etc/debian_version
7.10
tony@trinity:~$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
```

So not quite the same version of `rsync`, but the same major version.

As expected, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, `rsync` tidies up and does not leave any temporary files behind.

I created `A/` and `B/`, filled `A/` with some files, and then ran `rsync` once to populate `B/`.  I then just ran `touch` in `A/` and ran the `rsync` again.

I added a `-v` so I could see which file it was working on, but the behaviour was the same without the -v.

```
tony@trinity:~$ rsync -v -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")  A/ B/
sending incremental file list
archives/floppies.tgz
archives/fromx1.tgz
archives/homestuff.tgz
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(549) [sender=3.0.9]
tony@trinity:~$ cd B
tony@trinity:~/B$ cd archives/
tony@trinity:~/B/archives$ ls -l
total 78620
-rw-r----- 1 tony tony  7031885 Apr 15 14:44 floppies.tgz
-rw-r----- 1 tony tony  7031885 Apr 15 14:37 floppies.tgz.20160415144513
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 13959801 Apr 15 14:44 fromx1.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 13959801 Apr 15 14:37 fromx1.tgz.20160415144513
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 26136212 Apr 15 14:37 homestuff.tgz
-rw-r----- 1 tony tony  5727535 Apr 15 14:37 legacy-x1-scripts.tgz
-rw-r----- 1 tony tony  6636756 Apr 15 14:37 olddos.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 2 tony tony     4096 Apr 15 14:44 oldsites
drwxr-xr-x 2 tony tony     4096 Apr 15 14:44 temp
```

No temporary files.  So, maybe because the contents haven't changed, `rsync` doesn't need to create a temporary file.

This time, I have a single big file in `A\`.

```
tony@trinity:~$ ls -l A/
total 561528
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 574996664 Apr 15 14:52 bigfile.tgz
```

I sync `B/`

```
tony@trinity:~$ rsync -v -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") A/ B/
sending incremental file list
bigfile.tgz

sent 575066959 bytes  received 31 bytes  10953656.95 bytes/sec
total size is 574996664  speedup is 1.00
```

Then, completely replace `bigfile.tgz` with something else.

```
tony@trinity:~$ ls -l A/
total 572576
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 586311642 Apr 15 14:57 bigfile.tgz
```

That's a different tgz archive just copied over and over to make up the same file size.

```
tony@trinity:~$ rsync -v -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") A/ B/
sending incremental file list
bigfile.tgz
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(549) [sender=3.0.9]
tony@trinity:~$ ls -l B/
total 561528
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 574996664 Apr 15 14:52 bigfile.tgz
```

No temporary file.

Starting again, new file.

```
tony@trinity:~$ ls -l A/
total 433908
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 444315604 Apr 15 15:02 bigfile.tgz
```

Sync to `B/`

```
tony@trinity:~$ rsync -v -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")  A/ B/
sending incremental file list
bigfile.tgz

sent 444369947 bytes  received 31 bytes  32916294.67 bytes/sec
total size is 444315604  speedup is 1.00
```

Now, recreate `A/bigfile.tgz` with different content,

```
tony@trinity:~$ ls -l A/
total 545312
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 558392040 Apr 15 15:04 bigfile.tgz
```

This time, run the `rsync` with `--partial` and see what changes.  That switch is the one which usually forces `rsync` to leave partial files behind rather than clearing them up.

```
tony@trinity:~$ rsync -v -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") --partial A/ B/
sending incremental file list
bigfile.tgz
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(549) [sender=3.0.9]
tony@trinity:~$ ls -l B/
total 464596
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony  31424512 Jan  1  1970 bigfile.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 tony tony 444315604 Apr 15 15:02 bigfile.tgz.20160415150558
```

As we can, this time, `rsync` has created a temporary file (called bigfile.tgz) with the old one already given the new extension.

Edit: one set of tests again using `ls -la`.

```
tony@trinity:~$ ls -la A/
total 510488
drwxr-xr-x  2 tony tony      4096 Apr 15 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 89 tony tony      4096 Apr 15 15:12 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 tony tony 522724240 Apr 15 15:22 bigfile.tgz

tony@trinity:~$ rsync -v -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") A/ B/
sending incremental file list
bigfile.tgz

sent 522788155 bytes  received 31 bytes  22246305.79 bytes/sec
total size is 522724240  speedup is 1.00
```

So `B/` is synced,

```
tony@trinity:~$ ls -la B/
total 510484
drwxr-xr-x  2 tony tony      4096 Apr 15 15:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 89 tony tony      4096 Apr 15 15:12 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 tony tony 522724240 Apr 15 15:22 bigfile.tgz
```

Replace `A/bigfile.tgz` and resync.

```
tony@trinity:~$ ls -la A/
total 545320
drwxr-xr-x  2 tony tony      4096 Apr 15 15:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 89 tony tony      4096 Apr 15 15:12 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 tony tony 558392040 Apr 15 15:24 bigfile.tgz

tony@trinity:~$ rsync -v -a --backup --suffix=.$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") A/ B/
sending incremental file list
bigfile.tgz
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(549) [sender=3.0.9]
tony@trinity:~$ ls -la B/
total 510484
drwxr-xr-x  2 tony tony      4096 Apr 15 15:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 89 tony tony      4096 Apr 15 15:12 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 tony tony 522724240 Apr 15 15:22 bigfile.tgz
```

No temporary file.

I can't recreate the behaviour you describe using basic `rsync`.

Are you sure your `rsync` command is exactly as described, and are you sure it's not aliased somewhere to be something else?

Update:

Using your script, on a different machine,

```
tony@matrix:~$ ./rsynctest.sh
Creating a 500 MB file in A...
Now press CTRL-C to interrupt rsync.
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
tony@matrix:~$ ls -la B/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 tony users 4096 Apr 15 19:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 37 tony users 4096 Apr 15 19:54 ..
tony@matrix:~$ ./rsynctest.sh
Creating a 500 MB file in A...
Now press CTRL-C to interrupt rsync.
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(504) [generator=3.1.1]
tony@matrix:~$ ls -la B/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 tony users 4096 Apr 15 19:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 37 tony users 4096 Apr 15 19:54 ..

tony@matrix:~$ uname -a
Linux matrix 3.12.46-guest-39-a97a54c-x86_64 #4 SMP Mon Aug 10 11:59:25 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
tony@matrix:~$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.3
tony@matrix:~$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
```

Another machine, this time Ubuntu rather than pure Debian.

```
tony@neo:/$ lsb_release -r
Release:        15.10
tony@neo:/$ uname -a
Linux neo 4.2.0-34-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 10 22:13:01 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
tony@neo:/$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2014 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.

tony@neo:~$ vi rsynctest.sh
tony@neo:~$ chmod 755 rsynctest.sh
tony@neo:~$ ./rsynctest.sh
Creating a 1 GB file in A...
Now press CTRL-C to interrupt rsync.
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync: [receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
tony@neo:~$ ls -la B/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 tony tony 4096 Apr 15 20:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 tony tony 4096 Apr 15 20:09 ..
tony@neo:~$ ./rsynctest.sh
Creating a 1 GB file in A...
Now press CTRL-C to interrupt rsync.
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.1]
tony@neo:~$ ls -la B/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 tony tony 4096 Apr 15 20:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 tony tony 4096 Apr 15 20:09 ..
tony@neo:~$ ./rsynctest.sh
Creating a 1 GB file in A...
Now press CTRL-C to interrupt rsync.
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(632) [sender=3.1.1]
tony@neo:~$ ls -la B/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 tony tony 4096 Apr 15 20:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 tony tony 4096 Apr 15 20:09 ..
```

Comment: Note: Having realised after everything above that I had not used `ls -la` I re-ran all the tests and still can't see any temporary files even with `ls -la`

Comment: I've updated to version 3.1.2 and the problem is solved! Curiously however, the installed `rsync` version 3.1.1 on my fresh install of Raspbian Jessie Lite on my Raspberry Pi does suffer from the problem above. That is, despite being version 3.1.1, running my script above will generate temporary files that are not removed properly. I'm not going to fight this any more. I accept the issue as a bug.

Comment: Raspbian might not be following upstream patches fully perhaps?  Anyway, glad we got to the bottom of it!